# How to store same name when name column is PK and clustered

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

How do I store two employees that have the same name without  sacrificing the usage of the primary key index seek for searching by name.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.employees
(
    uniqueEmployeesId int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1, 1),
    name varchar(10) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_employees PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (name)
)
```

Comment: You can't.   PRIMARY KEY means it must be unique.  You could make the `uniqueEmployeesId` the Primary Key, leave the name as a non-unique clustered index.  But if you do, I'd suggest you pick some other combination of meaningful data columns an add them as a unique natural key.  maybe name and ssan, or name and title, or name and office phone number -  whatever.

Comment: This is what I did and it worked for that question. I am not sure if this what interviewer had wanted from me. ALTER TABLE employees
DROP Constraint [PK_employees]

Alter Table employees
Add Constraint PK_Employees_name_uniqueEmployeesID Primary key (name, uniqueEmployeesId)

Comment: That's very close to what I suggested in first comment.

Comment: If you have a column called `uniqueEmployeeId` which is an `identity` - ***why on EARTH*** would you want to make anything else the primary key?? This column really **screams** to be the PK for your table! It's narrow - it's unique (obviously) - it's NOT NULL - this is the **perfect** candidate for a PK ! Why make the `name` (which cannot be trusted to be unique) the PK?!?!?!?